# How to move a character in a console application C#

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I just started studying games programming and my first assignment should be a little escape room game, written in C#. I made a "room" with a 2D-Array and I want to move a character (displayed as "H") with the arrow keys on the keyboard.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKey;

    int XPositionCursor = 5;
    int YPositionCursor = 5;

    int MapWidth = 20;
    int MapHeight = 20;

    int GameOver = 0;

    string Character = "H";

    do
    {
        int[,] MapGeneratorArray = new int[MapWidth, MapHeight];

        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0);
            Console.Write("I");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(i, MapHeight);
            Console.Write("I");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
            Console.Write("I");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(MapWidth, i);
            Console.Write("I");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.SetCursorPosition(XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
        Console.Write(Character);


        consoleKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
        Console.Clear();                                        //Deletes the character at the "old" coordinate

        switch (consoleKey.Key)                                 //Movement of Character
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                YPositionCursor--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
                Console.WriteLine(Character);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                YPositionCursor++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
                Console.WriteLine(Character);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                XPositionCursor--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
                Console.WriteLine(Character);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                XPositionCursor++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
                Console.WriteLine(Character);
                break;
        }
    } while (GameOver == 0);
}
```

That's my code so far and it doesn't work quite well. After the room is displayed, the character is displayed inside the room, but as soon as I press an arrow-button, the "H" moves outside the array room and it can't be moved and the number "20" is displayed. I don't know why or what is the problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Do not overwrite the map inside the loop. Move the `int[,] MapGeneratorArray = new int[MapWidth, MapHeight];` statement. Also where is the map used for drawing on collision detection?

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help! It's so hard for me to understand everything right because I'm only 3 weeks into coding but you all helped me a lot ! I added a collision detection and now I'm working on adding a door in the walls and a key for opening it. Wish me luck ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are some ideas to get you going.

Note that you had the array for the board, but you were not using it well. Note below several pieces of code were *extracted* to simplify the core logic. Also, note that the array is updated and the draw method redraws every time. This could be optimized by making a copy for comparison and only redraw what has changed from one iteration to the next, just like the `prevX` and `prevY` allow only the cursor to be updated in the array. And finally, I changed up the data types make room for `char` instead of `int` and `bool` instead of an `int` for GameOver.

```
using System;

namespace stackoverflow_cli_game
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const char cursor = 'H';
        private const char border = 'I';

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKey;

            int XPositionCursor = 5;
            int YPositionCursor = 5;

            int MapWidth = 20;
            int MapHeight = 20;

            bool GameOver = false;

            char[,] MapGeneratorArray = InitializeMap(MapWidth, MapHeight);
            MapGeneratorArray = ApplyCursorToNewPosition(MapGeneratorArray, XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
            Console.Clear();
            DrawMap(MapGeneratorArray);
            do
            {
                consoleKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

                switch (consoleKey.Key)                                 //Movement of Character
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        YPositionCursor--;
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        YPositionCursor++;

                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        XPositionCursor--;

                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        XPositionCursor++;

                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        GameOver = true;

                        break;
                }

                if (YPositionCursor < 1) { YPositionCursor = 1; }
                if (XPositionCursor < 1) { XPositionCursor = 1; }
                if (YPositionCursor >= MapWidth - 1) { YPositionCursor = MapWidth - 2; }
                if (XPositionCursor >= MapHeight - 1) { XPositionCursor = MapHeight - 2; }

                MapGeneratorArray = ApplyCursorToNewPosition(MapGeneratorArray, XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);

                DrawMap(MapGeneratorArray);
            } while (!GameOver);
        }

        private static int prevX = -1, prevY = -1;

        private static char[,] ApplyCursorToNewPosition(char[,] mapGeneratorArray, int xPositionCursor, int yPositionCursor)
        {
            if (prevX > -1 && prevY > -1)
            {
                mapGeneratorArray[prevX, prevY] = ' ';
            }

            mapGeneratorArray[xPositionCursor, yPositionCursor] = cursor;

            prevX = xPositionCursor;
            prevY = yPositionCursor;

            return mapGeneratorArray;
        }

        private static void DrawMap(char[,] mapGeneratorArray)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < mapGeneratorArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < mapGeneratorArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);
                    Console.Write(mapGeneratorArray[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }

        private static char[,] InitializeMap(int MapWidth, int MapHeight)
        {
            char[,] MapGeneratorArray = new char[MapWidth, MapHeight];

            for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
            {
                MapGeneratorArray[i, 0] = border;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
            {
                MapGeneratorArray[i, MapWidth - 1] = border;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
            {
                MapGeneratorArray[0, i] = border;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
            {
                MapGeneratorArray[MapHeight - 1, i] = border;
            }

            return MapGeneratorArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the map array at all. Since the map does not change during the game, there is no need to redraw it at each loop iteration. Draw it once before the loop. When you move the cursor, first write a blank at the old position and then the `H` at the new position. This makes the movements more fluid, and the walls are not flickering.

We can also detect collisions with the walls. If we have a collision, we restore the old cursor position.

The code gets easier to read if we extract some code into methods.

```cs
private static void Write(int x, int y, char ch)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(2 * x + 1, y + 1);
    if (ch == Character) {
        Console.Write('╠'); Console.Write('╣');
    } else {
        Console.Write(ch); Console.Write(ch);
    }
}

private static void DrawMap(char[,] map)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < MapWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < MapHeight; y++) {
            Write(x, y, map[x, y]);
        }
    }
}

private static char[,] GenerateMap()
{
    var map = new char[MapWidth, MapHeight];

    for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++) {
        map[i, 0] = Wall;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++) {
        map[i, MapHeight - 1] = Wall;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++) {
        map[0, i] = Wall;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++) {
        map[MapWidth - 1, i] = Wall;
    }

    // Add some inside wall
    for (int i = 8; i < MapHeight - 5; i++) {
        map[12, i] = Wall;
    }

    return map;
}
```

I also added a beeping sound when hitting the wall. The variables `xLastCollision` and `yLastCollision` are used to avoid a repeated sound when the character is hitting the same place without moving, and avoids unnecessary delays.

The main code becomes:

```cs
const int MapWidth = 20;
const int MapHeight = 20;
const char Wall = '█';
const char Character = 'H';

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int xCursor = 5, yCursor = 5;
    int xLastCollision = -1, yLastCollision = -1;
    bool isGameOver = false;

    Console.Clear();
    Console.CursorVisible = false; // Make the default console cursor invisible

    char[,] map = GenerateMap();
    DrawMap(map);

    // Set inital cursor position
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Write(xCursor, yCursor, Character);
    do {
        ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

        // Clear old cursor position
        Write(xCursor, yCursor, ' ');

        int oldX = xCursor, oldY = yCursor;
        switch (consoleKey.Key) // Movement of Character
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                yCursor--;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                yCursor++;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                xCursor--;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                xCursor++;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                isGameOver = true;
                break;
        }
        //Detect collisions with walls
        if (map[xCursor, yCursor] == Wall) { // We hit the wall, restore old position
            if (xCursor != xLastCollision && yCursor != yLastCollision) {
                Console.Beep(800, 100);
                xLastCollision = xCursor;
                yLastCollision = yCursor;
            }
            xCursor = oldX;
            yCursor = oldY;
        } else {
            xLastCollision = -1;
            yLastCollision = -1;
        }
        Write(xCursor, yCursor, Character);
    } while (!isGameOver);
}
```

We get a better display if we use two characters per map position horizontally, because the characters of the monospace font are very narrow. By using block drawing characters for the walls '█' and ╠ + ╣ to form a big ╠╣ for the character and displaying the “H” with a yellow foreground color, we get a nice-looking console game:

[image]

Comment: Due to the nature of console text size, it would be better to use two character sprites and walls. Also, what did you use the capture the gif?

Comment: Since I extracted setting the cursor position and writing a char to the method `Write`, it easy to change this `private static void Write(int x, int y, char ch)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(2 * x + 1, y + 1);
        Console.Write(ch); Console.Write(ch);
    }`. I used GifCam.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be mindful of when and where the console is being cleared. Hope this simplifies the code. Check it out, it runs perfectly.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKey;

        int XPositionCursor = 5;
        int YPositionCursor = 5;

        int MapWidth = 20;
        int MapHeight = 20;

        int[,] MapGeneratorArray = new int[MapWidth, MapHeight];

        int GameOver = 0;

        string Character = "H";

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0);
                Console.Write("I");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, MapHeight);
                Console.Write("I");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
                Console.Write("I");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(MapWidth, i);
                Console.Write("I");
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
            Console.Write(Character);


            consoleKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.Clear();                                        //Deletes the character at the "old" coordinate 

            switch (consoleKey.Key)                                 //Movement of Character
            {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    YPositionCursor--;
                    break;


                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    YPositionCursor++;
                    break;


                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    XPositionCursor--;
                    break;


                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    XPositionCursor++;
                    break;

            }

        } while (GameOver == 0);
    }
```

And get familiar with the debugger, it is your friend.

[image]

Comment: `Console.ShowCursor = false` would be a visual improvement.